# How can show the rows of a table as columns in a new table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

How can show the rows of a table as columns in a new table

Suppose my Table is Like

```
tbl1
********
Sl#  Name
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
```

I Want to Return it as

```
tbl2
*******
Sl#   A   B   C  D
1     0   0   0  0
```

Comment: This question is unclear, read about `PIVOT` command in sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `Data Transposition`. A search would give you some samples on how to do that.

Few pointers :

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/5c5d810e-20e6-4d6c-a0a3-5277ba8de7e7/transpose-a-datatable-in.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TransposeTable.aspx

Comment: Much more commonly called `pivot` or `cross tab` in my experience.